# Convert links to https. Angular 2+

Tags: angular

My app pulls in thumbnail images from an api. The urls for the images are provided as `http`. I want to be able to convert these to `https` so the browsers don't complain about mixed content.

Is there a pipe or a better solution available in angular instead of converting in javascript?

Comment: Isn't pipe in itself, javascript?

Comment: Yes, pipes work via JavaScript. JavaScript is the only way of solving this problem if you don't have access to the back-end. I suggest not using a pipe, but directly manipulate the response after receiving it. Converting every http to https. Its more efficient that way.

Comment: Yes pipes is js but I was looking for a more Angular solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it inside canActivate guard, i was looking for a better solution, but for the moment i use this and it works

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

     if (location.protocol !== 'https:') {
         location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
     }
    ...
```

Comment: This is for making sure the app is delivered over https right? That is not what I am trying to do.